# Как реанимировать Punto Switcher в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

Всем привет, после обновления IntelliJ (сейчас стоит IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.2 Ultimate Edition) у меня перестал в ней работать Punto Switcher. Кто-то сталкивался данной проблемой? Как получилось решить?

Comment: Пробовали переустановить Punto Switcher?)

Comment: @Алексей, он работает везде, кроме идеи, думаю, что отгадка кроется в последней..

Comment: возможно программа находится в исключениях

Answer (score 0):

У меня не работал Punto Switcher в идее, т.к. идея запускалась от имени администратора, а Punto Switcher нет. Запуск Punto Switcher от имени администратора решил проблему.